# SSH config file limited to 100 identity files

Tags: bash, ssh, operating-system

I have to connect to more than 100 machines through SSH. I made an script to make all the connections and perform the changes that i need. The problem is that i cant type the password every time i execute the script for each of the remote machines. Then, I found out that I could create a file in the `/root/.ssh/` directory named `config` where I can store lines like this:

```
IdentityFile /root/.ssh/id_rsa_XXXX
```

The key pair is saved also in `/root/.ssh/` but the problem is that there is a limit of 100 identity files that I can write in the `config` file.

Do u know if there's a workaround to make this possible?

Thanks to all, first question here! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, if you have 100 servers to connect and 100 keys, you are doing it wrong. You can reuse the public key for other servers if you make sure the private key is safe.

If you are trying to load all the keys to ssh at once, you are doing it also wrong. The ssh config has a `Host` keyword, which can be made to filter which key is supposed to be used on which server. And I advise you to use it. Otherwise ssh will not know what key to use to which server and it also overcomes the limit.

Comment: Are u saying that if I use the Host keyword i can avoid the limitation?

Comment: Yes. If you load only the one you need for the particular host.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have separate ssh keys for each and every server? You could bundle them (one key for each type/function of server). Then you wouldn't need to specify each inside a config file.

Another way around this, would be to call the key from the command line, instead of a config file like so:

```
ssh -i /root/.ssh/id_rsa_XXX -l user.name server.example.com
```

If you do it carefully, you could create /root/.ssh/hostname where hostname is the actual hostname of the server you want to connect to. For example:

```
/root/.ssh/server.example.com
```

You could then script (BASH) like so (assuming you call the script dossh.sh):

```
key_and_hostname=$1
ssh -i /root/.ssh/${key_and_hostname} -l user.name ${key_and_hostname}
```

call the script like:

```
dossh.sh server.example.com
```